# Issue in testing my javascript file with jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

i had an html file, and in order to test it with jasmine, I seperated it into an html file and .js file and added

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js"></script>
```

to my html file and then I put both files in the src folder of Jasmine. now when i want to test, it does  not recognize the function in js file and says has no method.

For example, when i write this:

```
 describe("my function", function(){
it("Should return correct value" , function(){
    expect(myFunc(50)).toEqual(50)
})
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your javascript function using Jasmine you have to create a spy in Jasmine and do your test inside the spy method. A good tutorial can be find here.

> http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/spy-on-javascript-methods-using-the-jasmine-testing-framework.html#fbid=ng7_G9JElo4